# Iterate over JSON AJAX response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I need to go through each hotel key and go inside rates to retrieve some info, how could I get values of them inside this JSON on JavaScript:

```
[
    {
        "auditData": {
            "processTime": "1545",
            "timestamp": "2016-04-08 04:33:17.145",
            "requestHost": "66.226.74.194",
            "serverId": "sa37AUX3ROLBLIS.env",
            "environment": "[int]",
            "release": "2cb1bad878d2195c9b508e2007ef96616007dacb",
            "internal": "bz66k2etuxrt5q5h2zyf3jf6|MX|03|HA|1|3|0|1|3|N|||||||||1"
        },
        "hotel": {
            "checkIn": "2016-04-11",
            "checkOut": "2016-04-12",
            "code": 87399,
            "name": "Premier",
            "categoryCode": "3EST",
            "categoryName": "3 ESTRELLAS",
            "destinationCode": "MDF",
            "destinationName": "Ciudad de Mexico",
            "zoneCode": 10,
            "zoneName": "Downtown",
            "latitude": "19.431353",
            "longitude": "-99.156457",
            "rooms": [
                {
                    "code": "DBL.2D",
                    "name": "DOBLE DOS CAMAS DOBLES",
                    "rates": [
                        {
                            "rateKey": "20160411|20160412|W|71|87399|DBL.2D|CGW-TODOS1|BB||1~2~1|2|N@-644903865",
                            "rateClass": "NOR",
                            "rateType": "BOOKABLE",
                            "net": "687.31",
                            "discount": "111.89",
                            "discountPCT": "14.00",
                            "sellingRate": "799.20",
                            "rateComments": "Incluye desayuno americano para adulto y menor\nel hotel no cuenta con aire acondicionado  ",
                            "paymentType": "AT_WEB",
                            "packaging": false,
                            "boardCode": "BB",
                            "boardName": "ALOJAMIENTO Y DESAYUNO",
                            "cancellationPolicies": [
                                {
                                    "amount": "799.20",
                                    "from": "2016-04-08T23:59:00-05:00"
                                }
                            ],
                            "rateBreakDown": {
                                "rateDiscounts": [
                                    {
                                        "code": "DN",
                                        "name": "Descuento Niño",
                                        "amount": "-281.68"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "rooms": 1,
                            "adults": 2,
                            "children": 1,
                            "childrenAges": "2",
                            "offers": [
                                {
                                    "code": "9001",
                                    "name": "Descuento niños",
                                    "amount": "-281.68"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "totalSellingRate": "799.20",
            "totalNet": "687.31",
            "currency": "MXN"
        }
    },
    {
        "auditData": {
            "processTime": "1543",
            "timestamp": "2016-04-08 04:33:19.469",
            "requestHost": "66.226.74.194",
            "serverId": "sa3RKSJACHXE79K.env",
            "environment": "[int]",
            "release": "2cb1bad878d2195c9b508e2007ef96616007dacb",
            "internal": "bz66k2etuxrt5q5h2zyf3jf6|MX|03|HA|1|3|0|3|3|N|||||||||1"
        },
        "hotel": {
            "checkIn": "2016-04-11",
            "checkOut": "2016-04-12",
            "code": 87399,
            "name": "Premier",
            "categoryCode": "3EST",
            "categoryName": "3 ESTRELLAS",
            "destinationCode": "MDF",
            "destinationName": "Ciudad de Mexico",
            "zoneCode": 10,
            "zoneName": "Downtown",
            "latitude": "19.431353",
            "longitude": "-99.156457",
            "rooms": [
                {
                    "code": "SGL.DB",
                    "name": "INDIVIDUAL CAMA DOBLE",
                    "rates": [
                        {
                            "rateKey": "20160411|20160412|W|71|87399|SGL.DB|CGW-TODOS1|BB||1~1~1|5|N@-644903865",
                            "rateClass": "NOR",
                            "rateType": "BOOKABLE",
                            "net": "687.31",
                            "discount": "111.89",
                            "discountPCT": "14.00",
                            "sellingRate": "799.20",
                            "rateComments": "Incluye desayuno americano para adulto y menor\nel hotel no cuenta con aire acondicionado  ",
                            "paymentType": "AT_WEB",
                            "packaging": false,
                            "boardCode": "BB",
                            "boardName": "ALOJAMIENTO Y DESAYUNO",
                            "cancellationPolicies": [
                                {
                                    "amount": "799.20",
                                    "from": "2016-04-08T23:59:00-05:00"
                                }
                            ],
                            "rateBreakDown": {
                                "rateDiscounts": [
                                    {
                                        "code": "DN",
                                        "name": "Descuento Niño",
                                        "amount": "-641.98"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "rooms": 1,
                            "adults": 1,
                            "children": 1,
                            "childrenAges": "5",
                            "offers": [
                                {
                                    "code": "9001",
                                    "name": "Descuento niños",
                                    "amount": "-641.98"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "totalSellingRate": "799.20",
            "totalNet": "687.31",
            "currency": "MXN"
        }
    }
]
```

I was trying to use `for (var key in data)`, where `data` is the JSON response from AJAX.

Comment: Use `for-loop` instead..

Comment: How are you getting this data?... are you making an api call?? do you have it hardcoded?

Comment: @PatoSalazar The data is the response from a Web Service request.

Comment: Your json is wrong, firstly to take any action please correct your json format.

Comment: @SureshRatten You could check on any json online validator, and paste it, they all will throw it is correct.

Comment: And if you have limited API requests save the result(s) of one or more calls and use them for your testing instead of reaching out to the service each time.

Comment: @Aaron i paste your code on jsonlint.com and it thrown error 

Error: Parse error on line 131:
...rency": "MXN"  } }
---------------------^
Expecting ',', ']', got 'EOF'

Comment: @MartinSchneider I will do it, thanks.

Comment: @AarónGutiérrez also your json start with a dictonary [ and end with } which is looking incorect json format. LOL

Comment: @SureshRatten I just pasted the json code to JSONLint and it gives me a "valid json" response...

Comment: Ok then you paste wrong code or un-complete code on your question.

Comment: @SureshRatten The final "]" got out of the code snippet, that's what you're missing.

Comment: If you looking its good then ignore my messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an array. You should iterate using a normal `for` loop, like

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length;i++) { 
   var rooms = data[i].hotel.rooms 
   for(var j = 0; j < rooms.length; j++) {
     var rates = rooms.rates .. //do something with rates, it's also an array
   }
}
```

Comment: If I want to access "rates", how would it be?

Comment: I chose this answer because I rather go with for loop, which in my opinion, for this case, is easier to use

Answer (score 0):

Use a each loop each time you see a [] the first character in the string is bracket so we do a each we select the child in our case "hotel" using dot notation v.hotel,v.hotel doesn't start with a bracket so we don't need a loop,we go down in the json object until we reach the `rates` key where we see another braket so we loop and select the child element in our case the rateKey

```
    var obj =[
    {
        "auditData": {
            "processTime": "1545",
            "timestamp": "2016-04-08 04:33:17.145",
            "requestHost": "66.226.74.194",
            "serverId": "sa37AUX3ROLBLIS.env",
            "environment": "[int]",
            "release": "2cb1bad878d2195c9b508e2007ef96616007dacb",
            "internal": "bz66k2etuxrt5q5h2zyf3jf6|MX|03|HA|1|3|0|1|3|N|||||||||1"
        },...];

$.each(obj, function(i, v) {

  $.each(v.hotel.rooms, function(i1, v1) {
    $.each(v1.rates, function(i2, v2) {
      console.log(v2.rateKey);
    });
  })
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/78cpwq5g/

Comment: But I have 2 "hotel" key values, which one will consider when doing `v.hotel`?

Comment: both when using loop

Comment: if you whant the first you remove the `$.each(v.hotel.rooms, ` and in the inner loop you reference the desired hotel by position in array, exp: for postion 0 we do `$.each(v.hotel[0].rooms.rates,function(i2,v2) {console.log(v2.rateKey)}` notice the `[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Use the Json object.
If suppose the values are stored in JsonObject.

And some values you may want to retrieve.
Eg:-  **"code": 87399,
        "name": "Premier",
        "categoryCode": "3EST",
        "categoryName": "3 ESTRELLAS",
        "destinationCode": "MDF",
        "destinationName": "Ciudad de Mexico",**

```
$(JsonObject).each(function(){
     $(this).hotel.code;
     $(this).hotel.name;    
})
```